# C# lock free coding sanity check

Tags: c#, multithreading, volatile

**UPDATED**: now using a read-only collection based on comments below

I believe that the following code should be thread safe "lock free" code, but want to make sure I'm not missing something...

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
   //INotifyPropertyChanged and other boring stuff goes here...

   private volatile List<string> _data;
   public IEnumerable<string> Data
   {
      get { return _data; }
   }

   //this function is called on a timer and runs on a background thread
   private void RefreshData()
   {
      List<string> newData = ACallToAService();
      _data = newData.AsReadOnly();
      OnPropertyChanged("Data"); // yes, this dispatches the to UI thread
   }
}
```

Specifically, I know that I could use a `lock(_lock)` or even an `Interlocked.Exchange()` but I don't believe that there is a need for it in this case. The volatile keyword should be sufficient (to make sure the value isn't cached), no? Can someone please confirm this, or else let me know what I don't understand about threading :)

Comment: How does "Lock Free" mean "Thread Safe"? Isn't the point of locks to enforce synchronized access and make operations safe from multiple threads?

Comment: @StingyJack - Lock Free simply implies an algorithm that is thread safe without requiring locks.  Locks synchronize access, but can also result in performance or deadlocking issues, so avoiding them is always nice (if possible).

Comment: @Eric Petroelje - For the first part, I was pointing out that they are not necessarily related. For the second, other than a bit of syntax brevity, I don't see how eliminating the lock(){} is better or not.

Comment: @StingyJack There are actually several threads that read this data and one of them is performance critical. Using lock(){} causes performance issues that I'd like to eliminate if possible.

Comment: @StingyJack lock-free programming is rarely used outside the context of concurrent programming- I'd say they're closely related. Generally, nobody avoids locks for the sake of syntax brevity... if that's the main reason one should avoid locks, then you've missed the entire point of concurrent programming.

Comment: @Link and herbrandson - The exercise here is to make sure that you are synchronizing access to the _data member, so that reads dont cause exception if the _data member is being updated (refreshed). What is the difference between making it volatile and wrapping it in a lock? (FWIW, I have to use VB and am stuck with using SyncLock)

Comment: @StingyJack - The difference has to do with performance. If you wrap everything in locks, then only one thread can read that data at a time. In some cases, this can cause a performance bottle neck. Lock Free code attempts to write "thread safe" code without the use of locks in order to improve performance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on what the intent is. The get/set of the list is atomic (even without volatile) and non-cached (volatile), but callers can mutate the list, which is **not** guaranteed thread-safe.

There is also a race condition that could lose data:

```
 obj.Data.Add(value);
```

Here value could easily be discarded.

I would use an immutable (read-only) collection.

Comment: I think he reads the collection only in UI thread, so it is safe.

Comment: Good point. I actually meant to use IEnumerable<string> instead of List<string> as the property type, but making the collection read-only would be even better. The intent is that consumers of the class would not edit the data.

Comment: @AlKepp if all access is going to the UI thread the entire question is moot

Comment: @herbrandson - with AsReadOnly() it is looking much happier.

Answer (score 7):

I have no idea whether that is "safe" or not; it depends on precisely what you mean by "safe". For example, if you define "safe" as "a consistent ordering of all volatile writes is guaranteed to be observed from all threads", then your program is *not* guaranteed to be "safe" on all hardware.

The best practice here is to use a lock unless you have an extremely good reason not to. **What is your extremely good reason to write this risky code?**

UPDATE: My point is that low-lock or no-lock code is *extremely risky* and that *only a small number of people in the world actually understand it.* Let me give you an example, from Joe Duffy:

```
// deeply broken, do not use!
class Singleton {
    private static object slock = new object();
    private static Singleton instance;
    private static bool initialized;
    private Singleton() {}
    public Instance {
        get {
            if (!initialized) {
                lock (slock) {
                    if (!initialized) {
                        instance = new Singleton();
                        initialized = true;
                    }
                }
            }
            return instance;
        }
    }
}
```

This code is broken; it is perfectly legal for a correct implementation of the C# compiler to write you a program that returns null for the instance. *Can you see how*?  If not, then you have no business doing low-lock or no-lock programming; you *will* get it wrong.

I can't figure out this stuff myself; it breaks my brain. That's why I try to never do low-lock programming that departs in any way from standard practices that have been analyzed by experts.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. There are actually multiple threads that access the data. The goal is to eliminate resource contention for the data. Please help me understand this -  "if you define 'safe' as 'a consistent ordering of all volatile writes is guaranteed to be observed from all threads', then your program is not guaranteed to be "safe" on all hardware". If the data is read-only for N number of consumers, and there is only one (internal to this class) thread that writes to the data, what makes this unsafe? I'm not asserting that it is safe, just that I'd like to understand why it's not.

Comment: @herbrandson: Well, do you define "safe" as "a consistent ordering of all volatile writes is guaranteed to be observed from all threads" or not? *If you do* then your program is not guaranteed to be "safe", because the C# language does not provide that guarantee. If your definition of "safe" includes "it is permitted for any inconsistent ordering of volatile writes to be observed from the reading threads", then we still don't know whether it is safe or not, because you haven't stated what *you* mean by "safe".

Comment: @herbrandson: Now, if your goal is to *reduce contention* then then going to a lock-free solution is dangerous. I would concentrate first on *figuring out why you have so much contention*. If you have lots of contention because you have lots of frequent readers and only one infrequent writer then surely the way to eliminate the contention is to use a ReaderWriterLockSlim, no?

Comment: I wasn't familiar with ReaderWriterLockSlim. Thanks for that! But, would ReaderWriterLockSlim be better then Interlocked.Exchange() in this case? And if so, why?

Comment: Sorry, one other question ;). If there is only one thread doing writes, wouldn't there be "a consistent ordering of all volatile writes"? Thank you so much for helping me better understand this stuff. Threading is a bit harder to grok then the average programming concept.

Comment: @herbrandson: Define "better". My definition of "better" includes things like being robust, portable, understandable, testable, and so on. **I do not understand enough about CPU invariants to feel comfortable doing lock-free programming**. If you feel that you do, great. My opinion is that bugs in lock-free code are amongst the most difficult to detect, understand, debug and reproduce in all of programming.  I avoid it unless there is truly no other alternative to achieve the performance I need, and I get world-class experts to review it when I do.

Comment: @herbrandson: Who cares if there is only one thread doing writes?  That's completely irrelevant. The question at hand is: *is there guaranteed to be a consistent ordering of all writes observed from all other threads?* and the answer to that is *the specification notes explicitly that it makes no such guarantee*. If your definition of "safe" includes there being a consistent order of all volatile writes when seen from all other threads, then using "volatile" as you are doing *is not "safe"*. I don't know how many different ways I can say that.

Comment: Why wouldn't Interlocked.Exchange() be robust, portable, understandable, or testable (or at least any less testable than ReaderWriterLockSlim)? It should setup all needed memory barriers, so there shouldn't be issues with re-ordered code. Is that not correct? I hope I'm coming off as argumentative. I'm really just trying to understand how all of this works. I'm hoping that posting on Stackoverflow is asking world class experts.

Comment: "is there guaranteed to be a consistent ordering of all writes observed from all other threads" - I believe there is, but I guess that's really what my original question is about at it's root. Is there a scenario where a compiler/hardware optimization will cause this to break. And, if so, what is it? I really want to improve my understanding of multi-threading and how to do it well.

Comment: @herbrandson: *is there a scenario that causes this to break*? I don't know because *I don't know everything else your program is doing, and how you expect that volatile variable to be used*. That's my point; when you try to write multithreaded code, particularly lock-free code, you need to understand the whole program to know if it is correct. You also need to understand *everything* that the compiler and CPU are permitted to do if you're going to write low-lock programs safely, and you need a clear definition of "safe". I'll post an illustrative example.

Answer (score 0):

I think that if you have only two threads like you described, your code is correct and safe. And also you don't need that volatile, it is useless here.

But please don't call it "thread safe", as it is safe only for your two threads using it your special way.

Comment: Why would it not be called "thread safe"? Only the internal thread has the ability to alter the data and any number of threads could consume it. (Please note, I have updated the code just a bit to make the Data property read-only)

Comment: volatile is a curious beast; if the intent is to prevent register cache, then I think it is non-trivial to say when it is useless. It is easy enough to give an example of where it matters, but the opposite is not so easy. An example works for a disproof, but not a proof. Care to explain why this is useless?

Comment: @Marc: AFAIK C# has ordered writes and no global optimizations, so this particular piece of code is safe regardless of volatile.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that this is safe in itself (even without volatile), *however* there may be issues depending on how other threads use the Data property.

Provided that you can guarantee that all other threads read and cache the value of Data once before doing enumeration on it (and don't try to cast it to some broader interface to perform other operations), **and** make no consistency assumptions for a second access to the property, then you should be ok.  If you can't make that guarantee (and it'd be hard to make that guarantee if eg. one of the users is the framework itself via data-binding, and hence code that you do not control), then you can't say that it's safe.

For example, this would be safe:

```
foreach (var item in x.Data)
{
   // do something with item
}
```

And this would be safe (provided that the JIT isn't allowed to optimise away the local, which I *think* is the case):

```
var data = x.Data;
var item1 = FindItem(data, a);
var item2 = FindItem(data, b);
DoSomething(item1, item2);
```

The above two might act on stale data, but it will always be consistent data.  But this would not necessarily be safe:

```
var item1 = FindItem(x.Data, a);
var item2 = FindItem(x.Data, b);
DoSomething(item1, item2);
```

This one could possibly be searching two different states of the collection (before and after some thread replaces it), so it may not be safe to operate on items found in each separate enumeration, as they may not be consistent with each other.

The issue would be worse with a broader interface; eg. if Data exposed `IList<T>` you'd have to watch for consistency of Count and indexer operations as well.

Comment: I agree, but wouldn't the same issues exist if a lock() was used?

Comment: Yes, but if a lock were used (and publicly exposed) then the lock could be wrapped around the whole third block to make it safe again.  (And this sort of thing may even be done automatically by third party code via the SyncRoot property.)  There is no way to do something similar with the lock-free variant, short of introducing a lock to all users, or being able to rewrite the code to match the second example.